# Cargar una imagen desde una url con Picasso y poder hacerle Zoom

Tags: android, kotlin, zoom

tengo el siguiente código Kotlin que me carga una imagen desde la carpeta /drawable y una vez cargada le puedo hacer zoom usando la librería

```
"com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view-androidx:3.10.0".
```

Quiero hacer lo mismo pero usando una url de la imagen y no se como hacerlo, a ver si alguien puede decirme que es lo que debo cambiar para conseguir cargar la imagen de internet y pueda hacerle zoom.

El código es el siguiente:

```
package com.example.calen.calendar
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.ImageSource
import com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
import com.example.calen.R
import com.example.calen.databinding.ActivityImagenCalendariBinding
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso


class ImagenCalendariActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var imageView: SubsamplingScaleImageView
private lateinit var binding: ActivityImagenCalendariBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityImagenCalendariBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view)
    imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.calendar))
    
    }
}
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cargar imagen desde url usando [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)**

Para cargar una imagen desde una url usando `Picasso`, lo realizarías de la siguiente forma usando una url y definiendo el ImageView donde se desplegaría la imagen.

```
Picasso.get().load("https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:Android_robot.svg").into(imageView)
```

Revisa los ejemplos de la [**documentación**](https://square.github.io/picasso/).

**Zoom en ImageView**

`Picasso` no cuenta actualmente con alguna implementación para usar los gestos y realizar un "Zoom" de la imagen, pero existen varios proyectos de vistas que pueden realizar lo que necesitas, en este caso te recomiendo usar el proyecto que realizó Chris Barnes que es de donde se han realizado varías copias para la implementación del Zoom en un `ImageView`.

Para usar [**PhotoView**](https://github.com/Baseflow/PhotoView), lo que tienes que realizar es agregar la dependencia en tu archivo `app/build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
}
```

y las dependencias en tu archivo `build.gradle` que se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }   
}
```

en lugar de usar un `ImageView` usa la vista `PhotoView` donde agregarías la imagen que descargaría `Picasso`.:

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Jorgesys finalmente con tu ayuda he podido conseguir lo que quería, lo que pasa es que con la librería "com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view-androidx:3.10.0" podía hacer más efecto Zoom, quería preguntar si sabes si hay algún modo de aumentar el efecto zoom del PhotoView.?
Gracias.

Comment: Me respondo a mi mismo, para haumentar el efecto zoom del PhotoView lo haríamos de la siguiente forma:

import com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
val photoView = findViewById<PhotoView>(R.id.photo_view)
photoView.minimumScale = 0.5f // Escala mínima permitida
photoView.maximumScale = 7.0f // Escala máxima permitida